# Using DNS based system to unblock a blocked URL?

Tags: dns, youtube, ip

Okay I understand that this might be a silly question.

I'm looking forward to unblock Youtube in my country. I'm quite sure its a simple address/url block. I currently have to use proxies which reduce the speed of the connection. I tried to use the IP of Youtube to open it up but Youtube's IP actually opens up Google.com so that it is of no use.

I was also thinking of something like creating a DNS entry on one of my sub-domains that might point to Youtube's URL in some way but that might not be possible as I don't really know how DNS systems work at all. So some guesses might help. I'm not sure of some other hidden URLs that point to Youtube or even if some exist. So they might help as well.

Comment: This isn't on topic for this site, which is specifically meant for programming questions.  Further, if You tube is blocked in your country, that implies it's blocked by the government.  As much as we might disagree with censorship, asking us to help break your government's laws is not cool.

Answer (score 0):

May be using VPN connection to some provider that does not block the traffic would help? This one for example: http://privateinternetaccess.com

Comment: I use my own VPN through my own server so that definitely does not block any traffic but I still don't enjoy it like I do on the direct connection.

Comment: Your server uses the same DNS servers as your workstation does?